# how to make delete button in ctools modal form edit node act as default?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I've made a ctools modal form for add,edit and delete a node successfully.

But i need to make the delete happens as the default form act (the user could delete the node after he clicks the button edit )

I thought of sending an ajax request and simply do the confirm by another popup but my problem is how to embed a js code to the rendered form by ctools

Please help or advice with a better scenario

Thanks in advance